# Laravel 5.2 Auth validate not working any more when use Middleware 'web'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
Route::auth();
```

It work fine, but when i use middle 'web' (defalt by **Laravel 5.2.45**) like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
   Route::auth();
});
```

Routes still working, but all validate (email required, username required,...) not working and variable `$error` not exist).

Comment: Which version of Laravel you are using exactly? Since some minor version of L5.2 all routes are automagically wrapped in 'web' middleware, so wrapping it again will cause issues.

Comment: Do you have `auth` at the top of `HomeController`? `Route::auth()` just add route lines, not auth middleware.

Comment: @Laran I'm using v5.2.45

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Every thing work fine. Just variable $error not exist anymore. Login, logout, register work fine, but when i input wrong it not alert with variable $error.

Comment: @OmegaP In this case you shouldn't wrap all routes in 'web' middleware in this case - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: @Laran When i don't wrap some routes in 'web' then `ShareErrorsFromSession`, `EncryptCookies`, `VerifyCsrfToken` are still work?

Comment: @OmegaP create a POST form without csrf token and find out by yourself:) Hint: Yes, they do.

Comment: @Laran Thanks so much. I knew it, my laravel what i'm using, 'it is automatically included in the web middleware group'